# Magnolia CMS: permission to edit dialog

Tags: configuration, permissions, dialog, magnolia

#### In a nutshell:

Restrict component's EDITION via configuration.

---

#### In details:

I have some [roles defined in the Magnolia's Security app](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Roles+and+access+control+lists). I would like to restrict access (allowing to edit a component) to a dialog to a given role.

i.e. I have a `custom form` component with sensitive configuration in the its dialog (content of emails sent & so on) and I need to restrict the access to the relevant tabs or fields to `superuser`

---

#### Info I found

I looked into the [Dialog Definition documentation of Magnolia CMS](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Dialog+definition) and found nothing on this topic.

---

#### What I tried

I tried following a similar pattern as the one used for [Magnolia CMS' Template availability by role](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Template+availability#Templateavailability-Availabilitybyrole), using a `roles` node with a relevant child property (i.e. `superuser` property with value `superuser`).

But no luck, whether I add this node on the `<formName>`, `form`, `tabs`, `<tabName>` or `fields` level.

Comment: that's not ACL, but simple access to features/resources by role. ACL is object to object access, like user instance to comment instance (his comments).

Comment: @juanmf thanks for pointing that out. I mixed up the ACL concept & the role concept. As written in the [Magnolia CMS documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Roles+and+access+control+lists): `"The ACL itself defines what permission is granted."` and `"Attaching the ACL to a role defines who has the permission"`. I have updated/corrected the question